# Using Like Operator with a variable in MariaDB and Python

Tags: python, mariadb

In flask, I tried

```
with db.engine.connect() as connection
    query_str = "SELECT * FROM db_name WHERE name LIKE :condition"
    connection.execute(text(query_str), condition="%" + word + "%")
```

But it did not work. How can I fix the code?

Comment: When using `%` as a wildcard, you need `LIKE`, not `=`.  Consider using a `FULLTEXT` index.

Answer (score 0):

From https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-connect-python-programs-mariadb

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect()
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM db_name WHERE name LIKE %s", (some_name,))
```

The issue is that you are calling execute() on the connection rather than a cursor of that connection.